# How can I pull all objects of an HTML class into an array (JS)

Tags: javascript

For context, I'm working on a project that involves a layout with some slightly overlapping cards. I want them to stack in descending order, so the z-index of the first listed card will be highest and the z-index of the last listed card will be lowest. When a card is hovered over, it should be brought to the front.

I want to use a JS loop to assign the z-indexes so the list of cards can be more easily updated, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pull them into an array to loop through.

The HTML is basically:

```html
<a class="card">
  <div class="card-text">
    <p class="info-line-1">Line 1</p>
    <p class="info-line-2">Line 2</p>
    <etc>etc</etc>
  </div>
</a>
```

I've tried using Array.from() to no avail, and assorted messes involving, say, cardArray.push(card), but that's not working either.

I'm sure it's a really simple solution, but I'm totally new at JavaScript and I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: What JavaScript do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick them all in a collection and apply a z-index.

```js
let collection = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

let i = 0;
for (const item of collection) {
  item.style.zIndex=i++;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I originally thought it would look something like this. I think I tripped myself up somewhere along the way and somehow ended up trying to put them in an array, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("some class");
for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.zIndex = "7";
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The js [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object is an iterator and has the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, so it shouldn't be necessary to convert it into an array.

Since each card has a unique class name, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".card-text p")` to generate the NodeList.

As a trivial example, this will put the second card on top.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card-text p");

cards.forEach((card, index) => {
  if (index === 1) {
    card.style.zIndex = 1;
  }
  else {
    card.style.zIndex = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.card-text {
  position: relative
}

.card-text p {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="card">
  <div class="card-text">
    <p class="info-line-1">Line 1</p>
    <p class="info-line-2">Line 2</p>
    <p class="info-line-3">Line 3</p>
    <p class="info-line-4">Line 4</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: On further review of the question, i realize that I was looking at the contents of the card instead of the card itself, nevertheless, the same concepts apply to the solution.